# How to keep a dropdown value selected after form.submit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I know here are a lot of topics like that but I couldnt find a solution.

What is my question about:

I have a table with data and I have a input field for every column where I can filter.
Also I have a dropdown menu over the table. I can select different values there and with `onchange="this.form.submit()"` the table automatically adjust to what I have selected.

The problem:

When I select a value in the dropdown and then type in something to filter, the form reloads and the selected value resets to the first value. So it is impossible to filter. (except for the first value)

I am using CodeIgniter:

View:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="<?php echo site_url("workpackage"); ?>">

           <?php echo form_dropdown('wptypes', $wptypes, set_value('wptypes'), 'id="wptypes" class="form-select" onchange="this.form.submit()"'); ?>

        </form>
```

Controller:

```
$search = $this->input->post('wptypes');
    if (empty($search)) {
        $search = 1;
    }
```

After that code I have a function where I hand over the value `$search` as well as any filter values as paramter to the model.

So how is it possible to keep the selected value, that it is possible to filter for every dropdown value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your view section like this,

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="<?php echo site_url("workpackage"); ?>">
 <?php $wptypesField = (isset($_POST['wptypes'])?$_POST['wptypes']:set_value('wptypes')); ?>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('wptypes', $wptypes, $wptypesField, 'id="wptypes" class="form-select" onchange="this.form.submit()"'); ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

save your page as .php extension

```
<?php
if($parity == "none")
{
$sel1="SELECTED";
}
if($parity == "even")
{
$sel2="SELECTED";
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="get" action="(page name)">
<select name="parity">                                                         
<option value="none" <?php echo $sel1 ?>>None</option>                       
<option value="even" <?php echo $sel2 ?>>Even</option>                                         
</select> 
<input type="submit"    name="submit" value="Apply" accesskey="a" />  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

I needed to change my Controller to this:

```
if ($this->input->post('wptypes')) {
    $this->session->set_userdata('wptypes', $this->input->post('wptypes'));
    }
    $search = $this->session->userdata('wptypes');
    $data["selval"] = $search;
```

and my View to this:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="<?php echo site_url("workpackage"); ?>">
            <?php $wptypesField = (isset($_POST['wptypes'])?$_POST['wptypes']:set_value('wptypes')); ?>
            <?php echo form_dropdown('wptypes', $wptypes, set_value('wptypes', $selval), 'id="wptypes" class="form-select" onchange="this.form.submit()"'); ?>
        </form>
```

Thank you Muhammad!